# What happens if my passport expires while I am in the US under H-1B?

Tags: usa, germany, h1-visa, passport

My passport will soon expire, but my H-1B is valid until June and I expect to get my H-1B renewal approved in the next couple of weeks.

What happens if I'm in the country while my passport expires, if my new passport has been requested but not arrived yet?

I am a German citizen, which is part of the countries where the US does not require the passport to be valid for 6 month at the day of entry. I read somewhere that this is done by Germany basically guaranteeing that, for entry into the US only, the passport is valid for an additional 6 month. Does that mean while its expiration date is February, that I actually have until August?

Comment: Are you getting a new passport, and if so, are you getting it in Germany or at an embassy/consulate in the US?

Comment: What do you mean by "my H-1B is valid until June"? Your I-94 expires in June? Your H1b petition approval expires in June? or your H1b visa expires in June? If your I-94, did you get your I-94 at entry or via a previous Extension of Stay or Change of Status?

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14900/passport-renewal-h-1b-visa-stamping-on-soon-to-expire-passport